# Mixing CodeIgninter (PHP) with Backbonejs

Tags: php, javascript, model-view-controller, codeigniter, backbone.js

I just want to ask, does it make sense to use both a PHP backend MVC structure, mixed with a front end js MVC structure?

My question arises from building a web application in CodeIgniter, I've begun working with websockets and nodejs so a lot of my interactions to the front end don't even touch php. Currently though the only way to change content in my database is to go through CI via ajax calls.

Is there any advice and how to create and maintain both MVC structures? or should this be avoided.

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you already said: CodeIgniter is a MVC framework. As you're using BackboneJS you won't need the VIEW-part of CI and the MODEL-part won't be needed that much.

You could use CodeIgniter as a simple API backend that handles as a middleman between your frontend and the database (there are very good xmlrpc libraries for CI out there!) or you could go for a REST-specific framework like Recess (http://www.recessframework.org/), try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/238125/best-framework-for-php-and-creation-of-restful-based-web-services

Short answer: your php-backend would just serve as a API-provider which is used by BackboneJS, so you could use any framework as long as it fits your needs - and CodeIgniter seems to do that.

Tip: you can just delete the libraries and helpers from CodeIgniter that you won't need for you API.